# Read/writing to array of vectors with clock rising edge and read/write enable signal

Tags: vhdl, simulation, modelsim, quartus

I am trying to create a simple memory that stores vectors whenever the clock is `1` and `wrenable` is `1` (and likewise for reading), but unfortunately I've been facing timing issues:

Source:

```vhdl
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY test_memdata IS
    PORT (
        address, data : IN std_logic_vector(31 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');
        wrenable, clock, rdenable : IN std_logic := '0';
        readout : OUT std_logic_vector(31 DOWNTO 0)
    );
END test_memdata;

ARCHITECTURE arch OF test_memdata IS
    TYPE ram_type IS ARRAY(0 TO 31) OF std_logic_vector(31 DOWNTO 0);
    SIGNAL ram_block : ram_type;
BEGIN
    process(clock, wrenable, address)  
        variable write_addr : integer;
        variable write_en, read_en : std_logic;
    begin
        write_en := wrenable;
        read_en := rdenable;
        write_addr := to_integer(unsigned(address));
        if rising_edge(clock) then
            if write_en = '1' then
                ram_block(write_addr) <= data;
            elsif read_en = '1' then
                readout <= ram_block(write_addr);
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
END arch;
```

Modelsim Testbench

```vhdl
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY memdata_test IS
END memdata_test;
ARCHITECTURE arch OF memdata_test IS
    SIGNAL address, data : std_logic_vector(31 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');
    SIGNAL wrenable, clock, rdenable : std_logic := '0';
    SIGNAL readout : std_logic_vector(31 DOWNTO 0);
    COMPONENT test_memdata IS
        PORT (
            address, data : IN std_logic_vector(31 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');
            wrenable, clock, rdenable : IN std_logic := '0';
            readout : OUT std_logic_vector(31 DOWNTO 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT test_memdata;
BEGIN
    uut : test_memdata PORT MAP(
        address => address,
        data => data,
        wrenable => wrenable,
        rdenable => rdenable,
        clock => clock,
        readout => readout
    );

    PROCESS
    BEGIN
        address <= (OTHERS => '0');
        data <= (OTHERS => '1');
        WAIT FOR 200 ns;
        clock <= '1';
        wrenable <= '1';
        WAIT FOR 200 ns;
        clock <= '0';
        wrenable <= '0';
        WAIT FOR 200 ns;
        clock <= '1';
        rdenable <= '1';
        WAIT FOR 200 ns;
        REPORT "end";
        WAIT;
    END PROCESS;
END arch;
```

In ModelSim, this testbench works as expected:
[image]
But in Quartus, it doesn't work as expected for some reason:
[image]

But if I extend the `rden` and `wren` before the clock signal rising edges, it works:
[image]

I've been at this for a very long time, and would really appreciate some insight as to how I would be able to make the read/write happen when both `wrenable`/`rdenable` and `clock` are positive edged at the same time.

Thank you.

ModelSim-Altera 10.1d, Quartus version 13.0sp1

Comment: The difference in your two Quartus waveforms appears to be expressed by whether or not wren and rden are '1' when the clock rising_edge occurs. It can be useful to drive clock synchronous stimuli with a continuous generated clock. Using the opposite edge from the one used to drive the model can eliminate the question of order for synchronous inputs and clock edges.

Comment: In your simulation you have a race condition. In reality you will have a setup time violation. Read up on registers and set-up and hold time.  All-and-all that is not the best way to write your HDL code: Work with signals which are valid throughout a whole clock cycle until you have a lot more experience.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @user1155120, using the falling edge works but unfortunately my design requires rising edge

Comment: Yes your design requires the rising edge, You miss the point that in a synchronous a wren or rden high should have a minimum period of one clock and change as a result of a clock edge of a continuous clock, not asynchronously. When both stimuli and device under test are driven on the same clock edge. The enables take effect on the following edge. Using external stimulus changing on the opposite edge demonstrates which edge unequivocally, demonstrating both setup and hold time with respect to (here) the rising edge.

Answer (score 0):

Your memory model is wrong, you should only use one event which is the clock edge so remove the wrenable and address from your process sensitivity list, there is also no need for the 3 variables.

Good luck,

Hans.

Comment: I initially had only one event in the sensitivity list, and no variable use but unfortunately I still had this problem so I was trying many things

Comment: The process is capable of simulating properly as is and there is no problem synthesizing it as is. In -2008 using `all` in the sensitivity list would imply including all those and address in the last statement wait statement sensitivity list as well. That would simulate and synthsize correctly. The process could have more than the actual minimum required resumes and suspensions (memory reads or writes depend on the rising edge of clock. The variables aren't needed, signals can also be evaluated. If you don't like the names aliases can provide different ones.